# What drives the fields available for Azure DevOps custom rule actions?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to add a custom rule in azure devops to set the "Resolved Date" automatically when a User Story's state changes to "testing". Everything is good except when I go to add the action "Use the current time to set the value of...", "Resolved Date" is not available as an option. The list of available fields changes based on what needs to happen. I can see "Resolved Date" in the options for "Copy the value from..." but I never see it in any of the actions that write data to the field. Are the options for each action driven by permissions somewhere? Is there anything I can change to allow me to write to Resolved Date in a custom rule?

Comment: I suspect, but know for certain, these date fields have hardcoded rules that set their value. New, In Progress, Resolved and Closed are sort of meta states that always exist for items. And there are built-in rules to set these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Resolved Date" field has the `IsComputed` attributes to `true`, which means that **its value is computed by the system and cannot be changed**. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-workflow-changes?view=azure-devops#activated-bydate-and-resolved-bydate-fields).

**If you want to have a field that shows the time you change the work item status to "testing", you can add your own field with the "Date/Time" type.** Here are the detailed information:

1. Go to the page that you set rules. Switch to "Layout" tab. Click on "New field".
2. Fill the information to create a new field:
   [image]

   You can set default value and layout of this field. After you finishing it, click on "Add field". You can drag to change the layout of this field after you added it.
3. Go back to "Rules" tab. Now, you can use the current time to set the field you just created.
   [image]

Please refer to [add a custom field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops) for detailed information.